# Appending at a specific point using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am running into a major problem with openpyxl. I have 2 tables that I have to add data to but their names aren't set and their range is ambiguous. As a result I tried just adding a row and inputting the data to a new row. this helped solve my issue but created terrible formatting complications especially with adjacent data that was not in the table. Furthermore, I tried the same solution on another sheet using the following code

```
sheetname2 = excel_file3['Current']
sheetname2.insert_rows(10)
sheetname2.cell(row=10, column = 1).value = clientname
sheetname2.cell(row=10, column = 2).value = paymethod 
sheetname2.cell(row=10, column = 3).value = payment 
sheetname2.cell(row=10, column = 4).value = date
sheetname2.cell(row=10, column = 5).value = 'X'
sheetname2.cell(row=10, column = 6).value = 'X'
```

This code is problematic as it forces me to have to repair and save as the file every time I run the code. The error message it gives me on start up is the one saying that some stuff was lost and asking if I want to repair the workbook which makes me think it's due to this adding rows action.

Comment: If you change the size of a table you will need to update the definition yourself.

Comment: Do you have any images, charts, or other special objects elsewhere in the file? Any incompatible with openpyxl will be removed and give this error on opening. Inserting rows in openpyxl won't break an xlsx. But if you can open the broken xlsx and re-save it, it may still be broken afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ended up finding a solution that works really quickly and only requires you to manually confirm there are empty rows in your table.

```
 for cell in sheetname2["A"]:
    if cell.value is None:
        sheetname2.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value = clientname
        sheetname2.cell(row=cell.row, column = 2).value = paymethod
        sheetname2.cell(row=cell.row, column = 3).value = payment 
        sheetname2.cell(row=cell.row, column = 4).value = date
        sheetname2.cell(row=cell.row, column = 5).value = 'X'
        sheetname2.cell(row=cell.row, column = 6).value = 'X'
        break
```

I found this works super well as a psuedo way to append the values to a specific part of the sheet. I am even considering to add a starting point to get around the current limitation of having to have values in every cell above the table, but I am not sure how to do that yet. Either way hope this code helps anyone who needs a way to append to a specific point on a sheet!